# SSRS report Date format to be changed dynamically

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

How to show the date format in ssrs report dynamically changing based on the modification of the user preference in system? How to achieve it through the custom expression?
Need an expression format for dynamically rending date format in ssrs

Req : Its to show the output of date parameter value based on prefernce if the user modifies date format of the system to "dd/MM/yyyy" then the output should be in this format
"dd/MM/yyyy" if its modified to "MM/dd/yyyy" automatically it should render in
"MM/dd/yyyy" without changing the report design

Comment: I use a report variable for formatting dates

Answer (score 0):

You could add a Date Format **parameter** with two Available Values, dd/MM/yyyy and MM/dd/yyyy so users can select their format. Choose either format as the Default Value.

Then use that parameter in the Format property of each text box with a Date field.

[image]